# Getting the first item with a condition in an array returned asynchronously in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function called `getItems` that returns an array of objects asynchronously. Each object has a `isOccupied` method that returns a boolean.

I wrote a function that takes an index and returns whether index-th item in the array's `isOccupied` is true or false.

I wrote a function to return the index of the item from the array returned by `getItems`.

```js
    async getOccupiedItemIndex() {
      let selectedIdx = 0;
      return getItems().then(items => {
        items.forEach((item, index) => {
          if (item.isOccupied()) selectedIdx = index;
        });
        return selectedIndex;
      });
    }
```

I want to improve this function because

1. The fact that we are using an `async` function to use an array makes it lengthy.
2. I see that if there is no item found, it could return null?
3. We can assume that there will only be one occupied item in the array.

Any thoughts on improving this?

Comment: what does `isOccupied` mean? The code seems to just be asking "what is my array index?"

Comment: Is an `item` a restroom stall or does `isOccupied` mean the object's index in the array? OR are you really wanting the subset of  "occupied" items from the original array?

Comment: Is this function working correctly? `foreach` will return the last item that `isOccupied`, not the first

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**Array.findIndex()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) :

```
const getOccupiedItemIndex = () => 
      getItems().then( items => items.findIndex( item => item.isOccupied() ) )
```

will find first occupied index or  -1 if not found

Answer (score 0):

Since you are in an async function, awaiting `getIems` will simplify your logic, like so:

```js
async function getOccupiedItemIndex() {
  const items = await getItems();
  let selectedIdx = null;

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].occupied()) {
      selectedIdx = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  return selectedIdx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return the right variable. `selectedIndex` isn't declared. Only `selectedIdx` is.